# "SQL syntax error at line 1" but seems to be in my query

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1064

I am getting this error:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(`update_id`, `update_when`, `update_title`, `update_text`, `update_who`) VALUES' at line 1

I have searched this site and many others for resolution and I can not seem to find it. I have tried just about every suggestion that I can find, now time to see if I am missing something obvious (for the past 3 days). Please take a look at my code and see what is wrong. I have tested the code with random echo = "1"; throughout my code to find where it breaks, and I will post from there on. Many thanks in advance and if you need more that what I post, feel free to ask.

```
$update = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `cbhof_news` SET (`update_id`, `update_when`, `update_title`, `update_text`, `update_who`) VALUES (NULL, `$when`, `$title`, `$text`, `$who`") or die(mysql_error());
echo "1"; //this one is not showing yet, so I know its borked here.
if (mysql_query($update)){
        //header('location: news.php');
        echo "Posted! <br /><br />$title - by: $who<br />$text";
    }else{
        die('We are sorry, this entry could not be created. <br />Error: ' . mysql_errno() . ': ' . mysql_error());
    }
}
```

Thanks again!!

EDIT: Okay, my code now reads (thanks to Rakesh Sharma):

```
$update = mysql_query("INSERT INTO cbhof_news (`update_id`, `update_when`, `update_title`, `update_text`, `update_who`) VALUES ('', '$when', '$title', '$text', '$who')") or die(mysql_error());
if ($update == TRUE){
        //header('location: news.php');
        echo "Posted! <br /><br />$title - by: $who<br />$text";
    }else{
        die('We are sorry, this entry could not be created. <br />Error: ' . mysql_errno() . ': ' . mysql_error());
    }
}
?>
```

But now I am seeing multiple entries being made in the database. First it just inserted one, the second time two, then four, then eight....

Any thoughts?

Comment: ARE YOU TRYING TO UPDATE OR INSERT?

Comment: `INSERT INTO cbhof_news SET update_id = NULL ,update_when = '$when' ...` and also string values should be quoted with quotes not with backticks

Answer (score 1):

try to use single quotes on query variables and remove `SET` keyword Also close your query correctly

```
$update = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `cbhof_news` (`update_id`, `update_when`, `update_title`, `update_text`, `update_who`) VALUES ('', '$when', '$title', '$text', '$who')") or die(mysql_error());
```

For more insert query :- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html

using `SET` you need query like:-

```
INSERT INTO table SET col_name = value,col_name = value,col_name = value,...
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont use `SET` in the query if you are inserting new row

```
$update = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `cbhof_news` (`update_id`, `update_when`, `update_title`, `update_text`, `update_who`) VALUES (NULL, '$when', '$title', '$text', '$who'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the SET keyword.

```
$update = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `cbhof_news` (`update_id`, `update_when`, `update_title`, `update_text`, `update_who`) VALUES (NULL, `$when`, `$title`, `$text`, `$who`") or die(mysql_error());
```

And make sure your values are correctly escaped to prevent sql injection.

Answer (score 0):

INSERT INTO `cbhof_news` (`update_id`, `update_when`, `update_title`, `update_text`, `update_who`) VALUES (NULL, '$when', '$title', '$text', '$who')")

3 changes:

1_ Removed Set since you are inserting and not updating. 
2_ put ' instead of ` with the values.
3_ At the end you close " before you are closing the brackets.

Find edited code above, the code should work when you replace it.